# Best practices for testing MSI installations

Tags: testing, installation, windows-installer

The QA team at my current place of employment uses a custom built tool to test MSI installations.  The tool uses xml files to define the files/registry entries/services/etc that are included in the MSI.  The tool also uses a database to retrieve the file version information at run time.

Whenever a new version of the product is built, the database is populated with all the relevant version numbers for the build.  The QA team then installs the MSI on various virtual machines, and runs the tool, which will go and verify that all items defined in the xml files exist, and also verifies that relevant version numbers match those defined in the database.

Of course, this comes with the overhead of having to maintain the custom tool.  I've tried googling for ideas on how to make the process of testing an MSI fast and reliable, but my searches always come up empty.  So how do you go about testing an MSI installation?

Answer (score 1):

Via **Jenkins** to copy the artifacts to a QA box when it runs `Msiexec /i setup.msi /qn` to install the latest version.

Comment: sadly - this is still the state of things isnt it?